# How to test a function in model which has dependency on controller

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sinon, qunit

I have a formatter file like this

```
sap.ui.define([], function() {
  "use strict";    
  return {       
    someFunction: function(sKey) {
      var sResult = "";
      var model = this.getModel("somekey");
      if (model) {
        var oItem = model.getProperty("/yesno")[parseInt(sKey) - 1];
        if (oItem) {
          sResult = oItem.Name;
        }
      }
      return sResult;
    }
  };
});
```

and the model is defined in a controller `onInit` function like this

```
this.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(this._somekey), "somekey"); 

onInit: function() {
    // object containing the model data for header dropdowns
    this._somekey = {
      //uses ResourceBundle here
      ............
      ...........
    }
}
```

Now I want to test someFunction in my formatter. I am not able to figure out how I can do this?

I tried like this

```
var oModel = this.stub();
oModel.withArgs("headerDropdowns").returns(/* donno what to return here */);
    var oControllerStub = {
        getModel:  oModel
    };

var fnIsolatedFormatter = formatter.someFunction.bind(oControllerStub);
assert.strictEqual(fnIsolatedFormatter.someFunction("1"), "dropdown string do not match");                  
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't you test the formatter separately? All your controller needs to know is that the formatter was called. It's not up the controller to determine if something was formatted correctly

Comment: @Jorg Ya I understand your point. I am new to frontend testing. So was wondering if it is possible to do at all. In backend frameworks like spring, this can be done.

Comment: Yeah, I think I’d separate it even if it can be done (like Florians answer). Why fail the controller if the formatter changes? I’d consider the separation in spring, too

Answer (score 1):

```
sap.ui.define([
  ".../formatter",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function(formatter) {
  "use strict";

  QUnit.module("someFunction");

  QUnit.test("Should do this and that", function(assert) {
    formatter.getModel = function() {
      return new JSONModel({ "yesno": "<whatever>" });
    };

    var sResult = formatter.someFunction("abc");

    assert.equal(sResult, "xyz");
  }
});
```